# Reference for Hodge loci on moduli space of principally polarised abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties, deformation-theory, hodge-theory

Can someone suggest a reference to study Hodge locus, period mappings and period domains on moduli space of principally polarised abelian varieties?

More precisely, consider the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties of dimension $g$, denoted $A_g$. Using the Gauss-Manin connection, one defines a natural map 
$$\nabla:T_bA_g \to \mbox{Hom}(H^{1,0}(X_b,\mathbb{C}),H^{0,1}(X_b,\mathbb{C})),$$ where $b \in A_g, X_b$ the corresponding abelian variety and $T_bA_g$ the tangent space at $b$. I am interested in the image of the map $\nabla$. Is it surjective? Is it injective? I have read the simple description of the Hodge decomposition as given in the "Abelian varieties" book by Mumford.

Any reference/idea will be most welcome.

Comment: I am not an expert, (although I play one on television), but p.380 of Beauville's Varie'te's de Prym et jacobiennes interme'diares, suggest that, in the incarnation of the right hand space as a tensor product, the image is the symmetric tensors.

Comment: @roysmith If I understand here he is looking at the differential of the period map from the moduli of curves to that of abelian varieties. The Period map in my case goes from the moduli of abelian varieties to the appropriate Grassmanian variety.

Comment: Isn't this map really just the Kodaira-Spencer map $H^0(T_b A_g) \to H^1(A_b) $ followed by the cup product ?  In which case the isomorphism is pretty well-known.

Comment: @roy smith - What television show ?

Comment: @aginensky It does come from the Kodaira-Spencer map followed by cup-product. Can you suggest some reference in the abelian varieties case? Are you saying the morphism $\nabla$ is an isomorphism? I am not able to find any reference.

Comment: I didn't speak clearly.  The map from $H^1(A_b) \to \mbox{Hom}(H^0(\Omega^1), H^1(\mathcal{O}_{A_b} ) $ is the isomorphism.

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip a bit as my recollecction goes back to my (first) thesis days. The map you describe is an isomorphism on the space of complex tori and their deformations.  Suppose the complex tori you had was in fact a ppav.  Then the polarization amounts to a class in $H^1(\Omega^1)$ and the K-S map (cup product) takes that to $H^2(\mathcal{O})$ which has dimension $\frac{g(g-1)}{2} $ .  The condition that the polarization extend, i.e. that the variety stays algebraic is that this cup product class in $H^2(\mathcal{O})$ be zero. That is there are  $\frac{g(g-1)}{2} $ conditions.

Comment: So the moduli space should be described as all elements of $H^1(T_A)$ which 'kill' the polarization and hence the space of deformations of ppav is of dimension $ g^2 - \frac{g(g-1)}{2} = \frac{g(g+1)}{2}$ .  I hope this a) helps and b) is basically correct.  Experts ?

Comment: @roy smith - What television show ? – aginensky:   the simpsons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is NOT an isomorphism, by dimension count:  the LHS has dimension $g(g+1)/2$, whereas the RHS has dimension $g^2$.

It is injective though.  A (polarized) abelian variety is the same as a polarized weight 1 Hodge structure.  Such a Hodge structure on $H^1(X_b,\mathbb C)$ is determined by the subspace $H^{1,0}(X_b)$, and the RHS is the tangent space to the Grassmannian of $g$-subspaces of $H^1(X_b,\mathbb C)$.  The LHS is smaller because $H^{1,0}(X_b)$ must be Lagrangian with respect to the alternating form on $H^1(X_b,\mathbb C)$ for it to yield a polarized Hodge structure.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It will be very helpful if you also suggest some reference where I can study period domains on moduli of abelian varieties and similar questions.

Comment: Griffiths' two original articles "Periods of Integrals on Algebraic Manifolds," are quite readable.

Comment: A comment, just reformulationg what François wrote. The RHS can be rewritten as $H^1(X,T_X)$, the space of 1st order deformations of $X$. This is because $T_X \cong O_X \otimes H^0(X,\Omega^1_X)^\vee$ (using translation, the tangent bundle of $X$ is the trivial bundle given by the tangent space at the identity). So the map $\nabla$ is including the space of deformations as a ppav into the space of all deformations.